# Javascript dynamic post ajax/json not sending parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to send a POST dinamically in a javascript code to a PHP script.

It seems to me that there is something wrong that the data are not sending json data as parameters.

Here is how I generate de json data:

```
            query_string_fn = {};
            query_string_fn ["cdinterno"] = cdinterno;

            o.row.find("input, select").each(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                var id = $(this).attr('name');

                query_string_fn [id] = val;

                if (id == 'cdfornecedor_new') {
                    var cmbSelected = $(this)[0];
                    value_label = cmbSelected.options[cmbSelected.selectedIndex].text;
                } else if (id == 'cdtipo_new') {
                    var tipocmbSelected = $(this)[0];
                    tipovalue_label = tipocmbSelected.options[tipocmbSelected.selectedIndex].text;
                } else {
                    $(this).val(val);
                }
            }).end();

            if (value_label.length > 0)
                o.row[0].innerHTML = value_label;
            if (tipovalue_label.length > 0)
                o.row[11].innerHTML = tipovalue_label;
            editarFN_Post(query_string_fn);
```

Here is how I'm sending the data to php. There are some tests commented that I have tested:

```
function editarFN_Post(query) {
    query["action"] = 2;
        var data = query;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "funcoesFN_Fornecedor_Produto_post.php",
          //processData: false,
          //contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          //data: data,
          //data: data.toString(),
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          //data: {data: query},
          success: function(rsp) {
            alert ("Success!");
            alert (rsp);
          },
          failure: function(rsp) {
            alert ("Failed...");
            alert (rsp);
          }
          });
}
```

Here is the PHP code that I check if the parameters have been sent:

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo "action=" . $_POST["action"] . "<br>";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
var_dump($_POST);
```

None of these tests above return data.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this hitting the success callback? Also, switch out `failure: function(){}` for `error: function(){}`

Comment: @PeteGaulton, yes, it is hitting success is I comment the line:dataType: "json",

Comment: Have you tried using this combination `dataType: "json", data: data,`? And if this reaches the `error: function(error){}` callback, what error does it pass back?  (nb. use console.log(data) & console.log(error) for debugging to give you more readable data)

Comment: Yes. I have tried.
Using this, I get success if I change the php to return json.
In Chrome developer tools Form Data is shows in the place where I should see the post parameters:
[object Object]: